# Why is mktime() changing the year day of my tm struct?

Tags: c++, mktime

I read in two strings with a Year, the Julian Day (year day), hour, minute, and an observation.

I pull the relevant variables out using sscanf:

```
sscanf(tide_str1.c_str(), "%d %d %d %d %Lf", &y1, &j1, &h1, &m1, &obs1);
sscanf(tide_str2.c_str(), "%d %d %d %d %Lf", &y2, &j2, &h2, &m2, &obs2);
```

For this particular data set, the values are 2011 083 23 22 1.1

I then create and populate a tm structure, and run mktime, with cout calls on the day in between and it changes from 083 to 364.

```
int y1=2011, j1=83, h1=23, m1=22;
struct tm time_struct = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, *time_ptr = &time_struct;
time_t tv_min;
time_struct.tm_year = y1 - 1900;
time_struct.tm_yday = j1;
cout << time_struct.tm_yday << endl;
time_struct.tm_hour = h1;
time_struct.tm_min = m1;
time_struct.tm_isdst = -1;
cout << time_struct.tm_yday << endl;
tv_min = mktime(time_ptr);
cout << time_struct.tm_yday << endl;
```

Why is that?  Is it because the tm_mday and and tm_mon are set to 0?  I initially tried not initializing it all to zero, but then mktime returned -1.  What should I be doing differently if I only know the year day and not the month and month day?

Comment: The day of the year is sometimes *incorrectly* referred to as a "Julian Day".  In fact, a [Julian Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) number is the number of days since January 1, 4713 BC; it's used in astronomy.

Comment: Yes, but it is so widely used (incorrectly) within certain professions as to, in practice, be correct.  So long as everyone within a field uses the same jargin...communication happens.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`mktime()` is doing what it's supposed to do.

Quoting the C standard:

> The **mktime** function converts the broken-down time, expressed as
> local time, in the structure pointed to by **timeptr** into a calendar
> time value with the same encoding as that of the values returned by
> the **time** function.  The original values of the **tm_wday** and
> **tm_yday** components of the structure are ignored, and the original values of the other components are not restricted to the ranges
> indicated above. On successful completion, the values of the
> **tm_wday** and **tm_yday** components of the structure are set appropriately, and the other components are set to represent the
> specified calendar time, but with their values forced to the ranges
> indicated above; the final value of **tm_mday** is not set until **tm_mon**
> and **tm_year** are determined.

`mktime()` can *compute* the values of `tm_mday` and `tm_yday` from other members; it isn't designed to compute the values of other members from those fields.

What you can do, though, is initialize a `struct tm` with out-of-range values.  For example, if you want `tm_yday` to be 200 (the 200th day of the year), you can initialize a `struct tm` representing the 200th day of January.  `mktime()` will then normalize it to the correct date, yielding a `time_t` value that you can then feed to `gmtime()` or `localtime()`.

Here's a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    struct tm t = { 0 };
    t.tm_sec = t.tm_min = t.tm_hour = 0; // midnight
    t.tm_mon = 0;                        // January
    t.tm_year = 2012 - 1900;
    t.tm_isdst = -1;                     // unknown

    t.tm_mday = 200;                     // January 200th?

    time_t when = mktime(&t);
    const struct tm *norm = localtime(&when);   // Normalized time

    std::cout << "month=" << norm->tm_mon << ", day=" << norm->tm_mday << "\n";
    std::cout << "The 200th day of 2012 starts " << asctime(norm);
}
```

The output is:

```
month=6, day=18
The 200th day of 2012 starts Wed Jul 18 00:00:00 2012
```

Comment: I tried your advice and initialized like this:  struct tm time_struct = {0, 0, 0, 200, 200, 0, 200, 0, 0}  and the result when I called it back was day 77 when it should be 83, which is closer than the 364 from before but still off.

Comment: The standard doesn't guarantee the order of the members of `struct tm`, so initializing it like that won't necessarily work.  You should initialize or assign all the members by name.  But if they're declared in the usual order, you're initializing `tm_mday` and `tm_mon` to 200.  I don't think you want the 200th, or rather 201st, month of the year.  (And don't forget that `struct tm` numbers the months 0 to 11, not 1 to 12.)

Comment: To be clear, if I want year day 83, I should be setting the month to 0, and the month day to 83?

Comment: @RuQu: Yes.  Month 0 is January, so setting `tm_mon` to 0 and `tm_mday` to 83 specifies the 83rd of January, which will then be normalized to March 24 in a leap year, March 25 otherwise.

Comment: Yup, that worked, with the obvious 1 day offset from using 0 instead of 1 for the start. Thanks.  And kind of new here...how do I vote up your answer since it is in the comments?

Comment: @RuQu: You can upvote an answer (meaning you like it) by clicking the up arrow to the left of it.  You can *accept* an answer (meaning it's the one that solved your problem) by clicking the check mark.  Do either, both, or neither as you choose (this is me *not* trolling for reputation points).  You can also upvote (but not downvote) comments if you like, though that's not as meaningful; hovering your cursor to the left of the comment should reveal an up arrow.  In all cases, hovering your cursor over an icon should show pop-up text briefly explaining what it does.