# Get age out of date structure

Tags: c++, date, struct

I'm writing a program, in which I have some competitors, which are defined by structure. I also have a `date` structure.

```
struct date{ int d; int m; int y;};
```

I must sort competitor by their age, and I have no idea how to get age of competitors, to compare it.

I also tried this:

```
void age(tekmovalec comp){
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
time_t theTime = time(NULL);
struct tm *aTime = localtime(&theTime);

int day = aTime->tm_mday;
int month = aTime->tm_mon + 1; // Month is 0 - 11, add 1 to get a jan-dec 1-12 concept
int year = aTime->tm_year + 1900;

int age1, age2;
if(comp.rojDat.m > month){
          age1=year-comp.rojDat.y-1;
          age2=(12-month) + comp.rojDat.m;
    }else{
         age1=year-comp.rojDat.y;
         age2=12-comp.rojDat.m;
    }

 int age3 = age1*12 + age2;
 comp.age=age3;

}
```

But it returns error that `localtime` is unsafe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to sort by date, you may want to take a look at [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/). For comparison, you need to write a function comp that compares 2 competitors (you need just to compare their ages, using basic comparations between days, months and years).

```
bool comp(competitor a, competitor b){
    if(a.age.y < b.age.y)
        return true;
    else if(a.age.y == b.age.y && a.age.m < b.age.m)
        return true;
    else if(a.age.y == b.age.y && a.age.m == b.age.m && a.age.d < b.age.d)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

Note that this is not the best implementation (actually it is pretty messy), but it's purpose is to give you a hint, not to be used as it is.

Another way to achive this is to overload comparison operators for competitors.

Comment: In C++11, you can reduce that to `std::tie(a.age.y, a.age.m, a.age.d) < std::tie(b.age.y, b.age.m, b.age.d)`

Comment: If C++11 isn't available, you can use `boost` to do what @MikeSeymour said with `boost::tie`.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are using Visual studio. `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` needs to be a preprocessor definition (i.e. Seen before any `#include`s or code)

Right click on the project, get the 'Properties' menu and find the `C/C++` preprocessor definitions and put it thre.
To actually compare times, it might be easier if you use `mktime` after transforming your `dat` struct into a `tm`, but you'll have trouble if anyone was born before 1970.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575131/why-is-mktime-changing-the-year-day-of-my-tm-struct)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `localtime`. You do not need age; what you need is a way to *compare age*. To determine which of us is older, we do not need to know what year this is, all we need to know is which of us was born earlier.

Write a function that compares two birthdates:

```
bool operator<(const date &A, const date &B)
{
  ...
}
```

Then use that to build a function that compares two competitors, then use *that* to build a function that sorts competitors.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `localtime()` which can cause issues (not thread safe), you can use `localtime_r()` which should not have warnings :

```
struct tm *localtime_r(const time_t *restrict timer, struct tm *restrict result);

struct tm mytime; // use this instead of aTime

 localtime_r(&theTime, &myTime)
 int day = myTime.tm_mday;
 int month = myTime.tm_mon + 1; // Month is 0 - 11, add 1 to get a jan-dec 1-12 concept
 int year = myTime.tm_year + 1900;
```

*This might also be* `localtime_s()`