# Calendar behavior is not compatible with LocalDate?

Tags: java, java-time, localdate, java-calendar

Hi buddies I'm in a trouble trying to migrate a behavior from calendar to localdate.

```
payDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,payDay)
```

Lets imagine that `payDate` had the current date, 2020-01-29

for business reasons `payDay` can had the value of `0`, so, when the previous code line is executed with the previous scenario, the result is that `payDate` update the date to 2019-12-31, 
that is to say the the date back to the last day of the past month.

I'm not sure, the technical reason of this, if someone can explain to me this I'll be so thankful, I tried checking the java doc but it was not helpful.

So I need to replicate that behavior with LocalDate java library. From my point of view; the similar of `set` method from `Calendar` with the value of `DAY_OF_MONTH` in LocalDate is:

```
payDate.withDayOfMonth(payDay)
```

But when the below scenario is presented and `payDay` is equal to `0` I get an error:

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 0
```

Also I had some ideas about how can I get the same result of calendar in localDate when the rule comes on (if payDay is 0, return  to  the last day of previous month), but are too verbose.

If you know a similar behavior on LocalDate please help me. Thanks.

Comment: When you use `withDayOfMonth` you are saying "*take `25/12/2020` and replace `_/12/2020` with the value I give you*" . There is no zero-th of December, or any month. If you have some value that is zero-indexed then add 1 to it.

Comment: Basically, the `Calendar` API is distinctly odd - the docs explain it in great detail, but the `java.time` API is much more sensible... so weird things you got away with in when using `Calendar` won't work. If you want "0" to mean "the day before the start of the month" I suggest you write code for that - check whether `payDay` is 0, and if so, use `withDayOfMonth(1).plusDays(-1)`

Comment: @JonSkeet `LocalDate` has a [`minusDays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#minusDays-long-) method. Is there any reason you decided to add a negative?

Comment: @Michael: Not particularly. `minusDays(1)` works fine for me too. (It's probably just bias from Noda Time, where we only have `PlusDays`.)

Comment: @JonSkeet The `Calendar` API isn't that odd. The C `struct tm` and `mktime()` API had a similar feature, in that you could set fields to out-of-range values and it would adjust things to fit appropriately. No doubt the designers of the `Calendar` API were influenced by that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9575245/636009

Comment: @DavidConrad: We may to agree to disagree. The fact that it needs so much documentation suggests it's too complicated, IMO. (Things like deferred evaluation don't help, either.) I wouldn't say that the C API is a great example to start from - I completely agree that the `Date` designers were probably influenced by it, I just wish they hadn't been.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***TL;DR:*** Use `payDate = payDate.plusDays(payDay - payDate.getDayOfMonth());`

---

The behavior of [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) you're describing is documented in the javadoc:

> **Leniency**
>
> `Calendar` has two modes for interpreting the calendar fields, *lenient* and *non-lenient*. When a `Calendar` is in lenient mode, it accepts a wider range of calendar field values than it produces. When a `Calendar` recomputes calendar field values for return by `get()`, all of the calendar fields are normalized. For example, a lenient `GregorianCalendar` interprets `MONTH == JANUARY`, `DAY_OF_MONTH == 32` as February 1.
>
> When a `Calendar` is in non-lenient mode, it throws an exception if there is any inconsistency in its calendar fields. For example, a `GregorianCalendar` always produces `DAY_OF_MONTH` values between 1 and the length of the month. A non-lenient `GregorianCalendar` throws an exception upon calculating its time or calendar field values if any out-of-range field value has been set.

To show the effect of this, try setting the date of a `Calendar` to January 70, 2020:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear();
cal.set(2020, Calendar.JANUARY, 70);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(cal.getTime()));
```

*Output*

```
2020-03-10
```

You would get the same result if you did:

```
cal.set(2020, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 69);
```

---

[`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) is always *non-lenient*, so you can't set the day-of-month value to a value that is out-of-range. You can however get the same result as what `Calendar` does, by changing the operation to "add" instead of "set".

So, if you have a particular date, e.g. the `2020-01-29` date mentioned in the question, and you want to "set" the day-of-month value to 70 or 0, with same *lenient* overflow logic as `Calendar` has, do this:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2020-01-29");
date = date.plusDays(70 - date.getDayOfMonth());
System.out.println(date);
```

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2020-01-29");
date = date.plusDays(0 - date.getDayOfMonth());
System.out.println(date);
```

*Output*

```
2020-03-10
```

```
2019-12-31
```

As you can see, `date.plusDays(dayToSet - date.getDayOfMonth())` will give you the desired result.

Comment: Thanks dude you save my neck. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here’s how I would go about it:

```
    LocalDate payDate = LocalDate.now(); // or whatever
    int payDay = 0;
    if (payDay == 0) {
        // simulate `GregorianCalendar` behaviour: day 0 is the day before day 1
        payDate = payDate.withDayOfMonth(1).minusDays(1);
    } else {
        payDate = payDate.withDayOfMonth(payDay);
    }
    System.out.println(payDate);
```

When I ran the snippet just now, the output was the date you already mentioned:

> 2019-12-31

If we wanted it shorter, we could use `payDate.withDayOfMonth(1).minusDays(1).plusDays(payDay)` or the trick from Andreas’ answer, and we would not need the `if` statement. I would not, though. (1) It’s harder to read. (2) It doesn’t give the validation of `payDay` that comes for free in the snippet above.

The confusing behaviour of `Calendar` comes from not range checking the argument to `set()`. So day 0 of the month is the day before day 1 of the month. Day -1 would be the day before that, and so forth. It’s in this snippet from the documentation (or was supposed to be, at least):

> When a Calendar is in lenient mode, it accepts a wider range of
>   calendar field values than it produces. When a Calendar recomputes
>   calendar field values for return by `get()`, all of the calendar
>   fields are normalized. For example, a lenient `GregorianCalendar`
>   interprets `MONTH == JANUARY, DAY_OF_MONTH == 32` as February 1.

You may read it with this snippet from the documentation of the `setLenient` method:

> The default is lenient.

### Links

- [Documentation of `Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)
- [Documentation of `Calendar.setLenient()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setLenient(boolean))

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to just invoke one method to achieve the same results.  If you're **sure** that setting DAY_OF_MONTH to 0 should cause it to roll back one month (this is the type of thing I'd run past a business analyst or product owner for a sanity check) then you're going to have to do something like this:

```
    int payDay = 0;
    LocalDate payDate = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY, 29);

    if(payDay == 0) {
        payDate = payDate.minusMonths(1);
        payDay = payDate.lengthOfMonth();
    }

    payDate = payDate.withDayOfMonth(payDay);
```

Another approach:

```
   int payDay = 0;
   LocalDate payDate = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY, 29);
   if(payDay == 0) {
      payDate = payDate.withDayOfMonth(1).minusDays(1);
   } else {
      payDate = payDate.withDayOfMonth(payDay);
   }
```

Comment: I'd probably special case 0 differently - rather than work out "the day to set" just set to 1 and then take the previous day (see my comment on the question). I think that's simpler to read and reason about than subtracting a month and working out the length of the month. (In particular, it removes questions about what subtracting a month means for March 30th, for example.)

Comment: @JonSkeet That's fair.  I've added that suggestion as another option.  It has the bonus of not modifying `payDay`, which is probably a good call.